# CSS: Wrap all in a box with scrollbar

Tags: html, css, scrollable

I would like to make my current `activityList` contents be contained within a box where you are able to scroll within it.

I tried myself with [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AB4Ls/).

When there are a lot of contents though, it just don't care about the settings or give me a scrollbar with all contents inside.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding `overflow: auto;`

Comment: Cool. Never realised you could do that, haha.